# How To Add Mandrill Metadata Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, mandrill, webhooks

We currently use Mandrill to send our emails and this is working OK.

Now we wish to capture Mandrill webhooks back into our server and annotate the appropriate email source record with the event information.  In order to do this we believe we have to pass the ID of the original message to the webhook so that we can pull up that message from our server when the webhook arrives.

We believe the correct approach is to add a Mandrill metadata field to the message, but we're having trouble doing that.

We've tried the following (with variations):

```
Message.Headers.Add("X-MC-METADATA", "\"OriginId\": \"" + Id + "\"");
```

but the OriginId is never returned in the webhook and we don't see this header in the email's source.  It seems that we don't have quite the right format and that Mandrill is stripping this header out.

Answer (score 0):

The Metadata type accepts arrays so try wrapping the metadata with {}

```
Message.Headers.Add("X-MC-METADATA", "{\"OriginId\": \"" + Id + "\"}");
```

Check the API logs and see what the raw message looked like, it should have this content somewhere like:

```
X-MC-Metadata: {  \"testkey\": \"testvalue\"}
```

What I am doing is storing all the metadata in a dictionary, using a JSON converter to create the string and then stripping out all /n /r characters. The end resulting string is set as the header value.

Comment: It turned out be some sort of syntax error. I've been up and running for a while now. Thanks.